# Passing parameters from a List to a method

Tags: c#, list, data-structures, calculation

I'm solving my first training task and I'm at a dead end: I don't know how to pass values from List to the Percentile method. I can't figure it out myself. List gets the values from txt, and then passes them to methods for different calculations, such as calculating the percentile. I can't figure out how to link a sheet to a percentile.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace Fromtxt
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var filePath = @"C:\Users\Saint\Desktop\text1.txt";
            var numbers = NumbersFromTxt(filePath); 


        }

             static List<int> NumbersFromTxt(string filePath)
        { 
            var streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath); 
            var results = new List<int>(); 
            string line; 

            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                var isParsed = int.TryParse(line, out var result);
                if (!isParsed)
                    throw new Exception("no");
                results.Add(result);
            }
            return results;
        }

        private static void Percentile(List<int> list, decimal [] arr)
        {
            list = new List<int>() { };
            {
                int n = arr.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    decimal count = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        if (list[i] > list[j])
                        {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    decimal percent = (count * 90) / (n - 1);

                    Console.WriteLine("\nPercentile of stocks Apple for June "
                    + (i + 1) + " = " + percent.ToString("F2"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is arr in Percentile method. Did you mean to get the length of integer list  ?

Comment: in your `private static void Percentile(List<int> list, decimal [] arr)` method you are passing an integer list `list`, but just underneath you are initializing that list again: `list = new List<int>() { };`. THis most certainly is not wat you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call method NumbersFromTxt() only once in Main(), and want to use it results in other methods and you are not going to create another class for them, most preferable decision would be to create a field with this value. In your code it would be

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace Fromtxt
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var filePath = @"C:\Users\Saint\Desktop\text1.txt";
            NumbersFromTxt(filePath); 
            Percentile();

        }

        static List<int> results;

        static void NumbersFromTxt(string filePath)
        { 
            var streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath); 
            results = new List<int>(); 
            string line; 

            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                var isParsed = int.TryParse(line, out var result);
                if (!isParsed)
                    throw new Exception("no");
                results.Add(result);
            }
        }

        private static void Percentile()
        {
            
            {
                int n = results.count;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    decimal count = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                    {
                        if (results[i] > results[j])
                        {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    decimal percent = (count * 90) / (n - 1);

                    Console.WriteLine("\nPercentile of stocks Apple for June "
                    + (i + 1) + " = " + percent.ToString("F2"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I made changes but the percentile method still doesn't get the values from txt. The program stops in the Numbers From Txt method

Comment: Just in order to check, have you added Percentile() in Main()?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you already have almost everything set: you just need to call your `Percentile` method after you calculated `numbers`, passing these `numbers` just as you did with `filePath` for `NumbersFromTxt`: `Percentile(numbers, arr)`. (Don't know what `arr` is for, actually)

The only issue left is that you reassign your `list` in `Percentile` method, which makes your initial list "disappear" (`list = new List<int>() { };`). Consider removing this line.

And I don't think you need `arr` parameter, as you use it only to get Length. Try `list.Count`.